# Cannot change default port in NX JS project in React app

Tags: reactjs, command-line-interface

I try to change NX JS default port from 4200 to any different value.
I tried some commands which I understood from documentation that need to be placed into terminal and it didn't work:

```
yarn nx serve --port:3000
yarn nx serve myapp port:3000
nx serve myapp port:3000
```

what I do wrong ?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `nx serve myapp --port 3000`